# Lighthouse reporting unload listener error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I was working on the performance of my page, using Lighthouse in the developer tool, through the Google Chrome browser, and I saw that there is a problem with `"unload listener"`.

But the real problem is that I don't know if I can fix this, because apparently this is coming from the Google Analytics code or from Google Adsense. How can I solve a problem that Google reports, but which is also their problem?

Google Tag Services is the website from which the script with an error was downloaded

**Error**

[image]

**Source**

[image]

I really don't know if you can fix this, does anyone know if it's possible, otherwise, should I leave it as it is? This is the only problem in the *Best Practices* section, I would like to resolve

**EDIT**

**Code:**

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XDF203H0BD"> 
</script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-XDF203H0BD');
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you loading it from, your own site or a CDN and are you using the latest version? Additionally if you are able to provide a link to the unminified version so it is human readable that would be great as trying to decipher minified code is just a pain!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I use CDN to host my images. Now, I believe that this script that is showing an error is related to some Google tool that I use. On my website I have a Google Adsense link and a Google Analytics link, and in the [script code](https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js?cb=%2Fr20100101:formatted) that has an error, the domain is called Google Tag Services, so can we say this is for Adsense or Analytics? I really don't know how to solve something like that

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Here is the organized [code](https://pastebin.com/t9iD9xY7). Go to line 1688

Comment: Yup that is latest version, nothing you can do really without swapping the script out or editing the script and saving a local copy. It will just have to be one of those things you live with if you need to use GTM.

Comment: What do you recommend that I do?

Comment: What features are you using in Google Tag Manager. A lot of the time it is overkill and so could be replaced with simpler solutions. In terms of what I would do I would probably look to replace GTM due to it's size rather than because it makes the best practices score go down. The best practices score is purely for information, it has no real impact on anything in of itself.

Comment: I just checked my code, I just put what was requested in Google Analytics. I really don't understand about it, is there any way to solve this problem? In fact, I just wanted to solve this problem to achieve a 100% score in Best Practices, but you said the score has no impact, so should I put that aside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228180/discussion-between-anne-batch-and-graham-ritchie).